# Array sort on the basis of search text matching using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on some suitable way of sorting an array on the basis of search string. For example here is an array

```
var myarray = ["2386", "1234", "3867"];
```

and here is the string which I want to search in the above array

```
var searchkey = 123;
```

Upon sorting on the basis of search string, the result should be like this

```
var filtered_array= ["1234", "2386", "3867"];
```

What I want is

```
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    if (myarray[i].indexOf(searchkey) > 1)
    {
    filtered_array.push(myarray[i]);
    }else{
    unfiltered_array.push(myarray[i]);
    } 
}
```

Waiting for valuable suggestions!

Comment: Should `searchkey` not be a string as well?

Comment: yes, search key would always be a string like apple, banana etc. Its just an example what I explained.

Comment: I don't get the logic of sorting. What if searchKey is 238? Or 111? Or 321?

Comment: So you want the result array contains matched strings first, then the rest of original array sorted by alphanum. order. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, You are right. Most accurate will go at the top, 2nd most accurate will go after and so on...

Comment: @h_a86 You have to show your attempts to achieve the desired result. No pseudocode, the real code shown what have you tried.

Comment: Question edited with the logic I used. Please don't mark negative. Its a real question and I did not found anything like that on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var myarray = ["2386", "1234", "3867"], searchkey = '123';   

    function mySort(arrKeys,searchkey){ 
        var matchedKeys = [], notMatchedKeys = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < arrKeys.length; i++) {
                if (arrKeys[i].match(searchkey) ) {//dummy logic
                    matchedKeys.push(arrKeys[i]);//push on the basis of order
                }else{
                    notMatchedKeys.push(arrKeys[i]);
            }
        }
        return  matchedKeys.concat(notMatchedKeys);
    }

    console.log( mySort(myarray,searchkey));
```

Comment: Fantastic, thats all what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I have used levinstien for the string comparison, you can check the [fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/o7uun2oz/2/)

levenstien source = https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein,

my code is

```
function compare(a, b) {
    var leva = new Levenshtein(a,searchkey).distance;
    var levb = new Levenshtein(b,searchkey).distance;
    return leva-levb;
}


var myarray = ["2386", "1234", "3867"];
var searchkey = "123";
myarray.sort(compare);
```